# C# call javascript on scraped page

Tags: c#, javascript, web-scraping

I'm trying to scrape costs from page (TripAdvisor). The issue is that I need to scrape cost in several different currencies and I'm not able to programatically switch to different currency.

When I load page, there is this element

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var cookieDomain = ".tripadvisor.com";
var modelLocaleCountry = "US";
var ipCountryId = "274684";
var pageServlet = "Home";
var crPageServlet = "Home";
var cdnHost = "http://c1.tacdn.com";
var userLoggedIn = false;
var currentCurrency = 'EUR';
</script>
```

and I need to reaload the page so it displays for example USD as

```
<script type="text/javascript">
...
var currentCurrency = 'USD';
</script>
```

Could you please give me some hints how to reload the page and change the displayed currency?

The underlying code for loading page is:

```
var reviewUrl = String.Format("http://www.tripadvisor.com/Hotel_Review-d{0}-Reviews.html",tripAdvisorId);
var reviewDocument = new HtmlDocument();
reviewDocument.LoadHtml(Encoding.UTF8.GetString(new WebClient().DownloadData(reviewUrl));
//My assumption of how to continue
var scriptNode = reviewDocument.SelectNodes("//script").Where(node => Node.InnerText.Contains("currentCurrency")).FirstOrDefault();
scriptNode -> Replace currentCurrency property -> ReloadPage
```

Comment: can you give us some more details and code? For example how would you like to trigger the switch? Using a button? using a link with has an parameter in his url?

Comment: I'm not sure what do you mean. Right now, the code just loads the page and then crawls through elements desired. TA determines the currency by itself, which is for me CZK. I need to somehow accomplish this (just my assumption of how it should work):

public HtmlDocument ReloadWithnewCurrency(string url, string     currencyCode)
{
var document = new HtmlDocument.Load(Encoding.UTF8.GetString(new WebClient().DownloadData(url);
return document.ReloadWithNewCurrency(currencyCode));
} Or something like that...